# Init class properties

Tags: javascript, oop

i have some javascript class `someClass` and have initialization function `init` which check constructor params. Object with this params are rather huge and this function became too large.

```
function SomeClass (paramObj) {
    this.inputHourId;
    this.inputHourName;
    this.inputHourValue;
    ......
    ......
    this.Init = function (paramObj) {
        if (typeof paramObj.hourOptions.inputName == "undefined") {
            this.inputHourName = "default_name";
        } else {
            this.inputHourName = paramObj.hourOptions.inputName;
        }

        if (typeof paramObj.hourOptions.inputValue == "undefined") {
            this.inputHourValue = "default_value";
        } else {
            this.inputHourValue = paramObj.hourOptions.inputValue;
        }
        ......
        ......
        ......
    }
    this.Init(paramObj);
}
```

To avoid code duplication and make it more readable i decide to create function which will do var initialization with check

```
this.initVar = function (veriable, value) {
    if (typeof value == "undefined") {
        veriable = "some_default_value";
    } else {
        veriable = val;
    }
}
```

after adding `initVar` function, my `Init` function should look like that:

```
this.Init = function (paramObj) {
    // Input hour initialization
    this.initVar(this.inputHourId, paramObj.hourOptions.inputId);
    this.initVar(this.inputHourName, 
paramObj.hourOptions.inputName);
    this.initVar(this.inputHourValue, paramObj.hourOptions.inputValue);
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

but after that class vars `this.inputHourName` are still `undefined`

Now the question. How can I init my class property with the help of function? Or how can i transmit class property like function parametr?

Comment: JavaScript has no call-by-reference.

Comment: Please, put the functions on the prototype or omit them and do it directly in the constructor function.

Comment: as a side note, in JS you can also just do `varieble = value || 'default value';`

Comment: I undertand this, but how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you pass `this.inputHourId` to `initVar()` it will make a copy of the variable when it's being updated; that's not what you want.

You can rewrite `initVar()` to this; it uses the name of the variable as a string rather than the variable itself. Then it uses `this[variable]` to update the actual instance variable.

```
this.initVar = function (variable, value) {
    if (typeof value == "undefined") {
        this[variable] = "some_default_value";
    } else {
        this[variable] = val;
    }
}
```

Then, you call it like:

```
this.initVar('inputHourId', paramObj.hourOptions.inputId);
```

Comment: @bfavaretto Wow, that's a striking similarity :)

Comment: Can i do the same to init Eventhandler functions, just change `if (typeof value == "undefined") {` to `if (typeof value == "function") {`  ?

Answer (score 1):

also you can use this syntax instead of your bunch of ifs :

`this.param1 = params.param1 || "default_value";`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I init my class property with the help of function?

Since you can't pass a reference of the property which you want to assign to to the function, just return the value from the function and assign the result to the property:

```
this.inputHourId = initVar(paramObj.hourOptions.inputId);
```